# Block µTorrent ads

Tags: macos

Recently, I upgraded to µTorrent 1.8.7 and found that it has annoying ad in the side bar which was not present in the earlier version. Can someone explain that how can I stop the ads?

Comment: Or switch to Transmission, or other client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for the ad removal is to remove the new uTorrent and install the older version of the app. You can get it from the site below.

[uTorrent 1.8.4](http://www.oldversion.com/mac/utorrent-1-8-4-1)

Answer (score 6):

As per this post:
https://pietrodn.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/how-to-block-advertisements-on-utorrent-1-8-6-for-mac-os-x-using-the-hosts-file/

> Luckily, we can simply block the uTorrent ad servers at system-level,
>   editing the hosts file. Using the free network analyzer Wireshark I
>   easily discovered which servers uTorrent connects to, to fetch the
>   ads.
>
> To block those ads, first quit uTorrent. Then open the `/etc/hosts` file
>   with your favorite text-editor (you’ll need root privileges) and
>   append the following lines:
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1 cdn.bitmedianetwork.com
> 127.0.0.1 static.ap.bittorrent.com
> ```
>
> Next, trash the `~/Library/Caches/com.bittorrent.uTorrent` folder in
>   order to get rid of any cached ads. Now restart uTorrent, et voila:
>   the ads are gone!

Comment: After trying countless other websites which said to set advanced settings, swap the ad picture, or download other host files -- none of those schemes worked. You had the correct answer. Thank you sincerely.

Answer (score 3):

one option is to just hide the sidebar

View>Hide Sidebar

Comment: I am doing that currently. But is there any way to fully block it ?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry!